# Open a notebook in current workspace from a link with JupyterLab

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

I need to open a notebook from another notebook with a (markdown) link.
But I don't want to open the linked notebook, in another browser tab. Instead it should be opened in the current JupyterLab workspace / session.

I tried http://localhost:8888/lab/tree/path/to/notebook.ipynb but it open a new browser tab, request to switch to new workspace, and finally doesn't open the notebook.

http://localhost:8888/tree/path/to/notebook.ipynb open the file, but in the classic Jupyter view, and in another browser tab.

Is it possible to create a link to open a notebook in the same JupyterLab workspace ?

Comment: I have got the same question. I want to open links from another browser-based software. Looking forward to answers!

Comment: This is seems to be the issue in my case https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/3947, as I use remote server for Jupyter.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it works only when I paste `sharable link` in into browser when `jupyter lab` current `workspace` is active. Having that, it does not try to create new workspace and opens desired notebook successfully.