# Double click to open .ipynb with already running jupyter lab

Tags: ubuntu, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab

I figured out how to open an ipython notebook with jupyter lab by double clicking. I created the file at `~/.local/share/applications` (Ubuntu 20.04)

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Version=1.0
Name=Jupyter-lab
# This is for opening files, not launching the notebook from a menu
NoDisplay=true
Exec=/path_to_python/bin/jupyter-lab %f
Terminal=false
```

But if I open multiple such files, each creates its own browser-tab/server with different ports. What I want is that all of the ipython notebooks open on the same jupyter lab server as multiple tabs (in jupyter lab not in the web browser). Can it be done?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54882884/open-a-notebook-in-current-workspace-from-a-link-with-jupyterlab. This is a good question, I would like that too. You may wan to ask this in https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab_app which recently got revived and will probably have a release by the end of the year (I would hope so).